# How does android build system work?

Tags: android, build, kernel, gnu-make

I like to have a high level understanding of how the android build system work. That is when does it complement the GNU make and the Linux build system and when and how does it differ? What I mean by this is how come sometimes we use make files to add functionality to the final image, and sometimes we use Andoroid.mk? Then again sometimes we use both. Does anyone have a good grasp of how these components work together?

For example, I used just a make file to add a simple program as a module. On the other hand, looking at the /external directory some of the modules have Android.mk file and some have a make file also. Then there is the bionic directory.  Can anyone elaborate please?

@ arkascha- I appreciate this but I think there is a little more to it. It seems to me that GNU make has control over the Linux kernel directories and Android.mk over the Android folders; this sounds intuitive doesn't it? I was looking for a comment that would take this further and elaborate on which files need to be updated in order to add functionality. ie. looking at my build environment I have:

```
0628Samsung                 build.sh       Documentation  include          Makefile           packages         sound
abi                         config-backup  drivers        init             Makefile.bak       pdk              system
AndroidKernel.mk            COPYING        drivres        ipc              Makefile-original  Platform.tar.gz  tools
arch                        CREDITS        dtbTool        Kbuild           mkbootimg          prebuilts        usr
art                         crypto         external       Kconfig          mm                 README           vendor
bin                         cts            files          kernel           modules.order      REPORTING-BUGS   virt
bionic                      dalvik         firmware       Kernel.tar.gz    ndk                samples
block                       developers     frameworks     lib              net                scripts
bootable                    development    fs             libcore          note3              sdk
build                       device         github-repo    libnativehelper  out                security
build_msm8974pro_kernel.sh  docs           hardware       MAINTAINERS      output
```

I ask this question since there does not seem to be clear understanding of the AOSP environment. For instance, [this](http://elinux.org/Android_Build_System) link has a section called steps for adding a new program to the Android source tree. In it they advise updating the core/main.mk file. But my environment does not really have the lines they mention. Also sometimes one does not really have a choice of using one, make file vs. android.mk, or the other. At least that has been my experience. Maybe I missed something, but what I did was to add a sample program to the external directory. I was able to compile it with the same toolchain I used to create an image and flash my phone. But the executable did not run on my phone, which led me to believe that perhaps I needed to issue other switches and set various environment variables. So I kept trying to build the image with the program included, but the build environment did not go in that directory. After looking through other directories, I realized that most of them had an Android.mk file so I added one in, and it is chugging along right now. I'll let you know how it turns out. That is why I am asking this question. Maybe I am not looking at the right place, there is no clear stable content about how to add functionality to the final image and what are the differences between what resides in each folder. There is a high level description but no discussion on here is how you add a module to this /external, /bionic, ...and here is what the end result would be.

@Dan Albert- Thanks. I am trying to map what is in the /external directory with what is on my device in an effort to get my code into the image. I am not having much luck. I followed a set of procedures to get a simple kernel module in. But I just used a simple make file as follows:

```
lib_src := src 
lib_headers := headers 
.PHONY: all $(lib_src) $(lib_headers)
$(lib_src) :
    $(MAKE) --directory=$@
    $(lib_*): $(MAKE) --directory=$@

obj-$(CONFIG_TOS)   += examples.o
```

So when you say Android just uses Android.mk, I wonder. The reason being, here I just used a make file and I was able to see the resulting code in my image. Further, I'll share another example with you. Within the Android Studio projects, in order to get some native project in, you have to create a make file as well as an Android.mk. So....? There has to be more; no? Each file does have some unique functionality within the build system; don't you agree? 
Please note, I am just making this argument in an effort to get my code into the finale image.

I believe I heard what is in /external directory just goes into the /system folder of the final image. But I can not validate that. Here is what is in my external directory:

```
aac              droiddriver              hyphenation     libpng            nist-sip       sonivox
android-clat     dropbear                 icu4c           libppp            noto-fonts     speex
android-mock     e2fsprogs                iproute2        libselinux        oauth          sqlite
ant-glob         easymock                 ipsec-tools     libsepol          objenesis      srec
antlr            ebtables                 iptables        libusb            okhttp         srtp
apache-harmony   eclipse-basebuilder      iputils         libusb-compat     opencv         stlport
apache-http      eclipse-windowbuilder    jack            libvorbis         openfst        strace
apache-qp        eigen                    javasqlite      libvpx            openssh        stressapptest
apache-xml       elfutils                 javassist       libxml2           openssl        svox
arduino          embunit                  jdiff           libxslt           open-vcdiff    tagsoup
bison            emma                     jhead           libyuv            oprofile       tcpdump
blktrace         esd                      jmdns           linux-tools-perf  pixman         temp
bluetooth        expat                    jmonkeyengine   littlemock        ppp            timezonepicker-support
bouncycastle     eyes-free                jpeg            llvm              proguard       tinyalsa
brctl            fdlibm                   jsilver         lzma              protobuf       tinycompress
bsdiff           flac                     jsr305          marisa-trie       qemu           tinyxml
bzip2            freetype                 junit           markdown          qemu-pc-bios   tinyxml2
ceres-solver     fsck_msdos               kernel-headers  mdnsresponder     regex-re2      tremolo
checkpolicy      ganymed-ssh2             libcap-ng       mesa3d            replicaisland  v8
chromium         gcc-demangle             libffi          mksh              robolectric    valgrind
chromium-libpac  genext2fs                libgsm          mockito           safe-iop       webkit
chromium_org     giflib                   liblzf          mockwebserver     scrypt         webp
chromium-trace   google-diff-match-patch  libmtp          mp4parser         sepolicy       webrtc
clang            grub                     libnfc-nci      mtpd              sfntly         wpa_supplicant_8
compiler-rt      gtest                    libnfc-nxp      naver-fonts       shahin         xmlwriter
dexmaker         guava                    libnl-headers   netcat            sil-fonts      xmp_toolkit
dhcpcd           hamcrest                 libogg          netperf           skia           yaffs2
dnsmasq          harfbuzz                 libpcap         neven             smack          zlib
doclava          harfbuzz_ng              libphonenumber  nist-pkits        smali          zxing
```

This is basically what I have in the external/shahin directory:

```
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/external/shahin$ more Android.mk 
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= hello_world.S       
LOCAL_MODULE := shahin 
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
sansari@ubuntu:~/WORKING_DIRECTORY/external/shahin$ more hello_world.S 
.syntax unified  

.global main  
main:  
    push    {ip, lr}  

    ldr     r0, =message  
    bl      printf  

    mov     r0, #0    @ Return 0.  

    pop     {ip, pc}  

message:  
    .asciz "Hello, world.\n"
```

A simple assembly code and an Android.mk file. But when I issue make from the root of the project I am not sure if this is added to the final image. I don't see any object file created afterwards in this directory. Am I mistaken perhaps? My question is how do I get this into the final image?

Comment: It is just like having 3 different hammers in your toolbox. You can use each for hammering a nail into the wall. So maybe one hammer in the toolbox would be enough. But then again: sometimes different types of hammers make sense. A heavy one, a lightweight one, a precise one, a slip safe one, ... And also: hammers just seem to get offspring when left in dark, unobserved toolboxes....

Answer (score 0):

Only Android.mk is used by the Android platform build system. There are normal makefiles in the `external/` directory because those projects use make when built outside Android, and we just mirror their source. Still, we only use the Android.mk to build it for Android.

Bionic is no different than the other projects in Android, it just has somewhat more complicated Android.mk structure to deal with the complexity of CPU specific sources and various issues that come along with building low level system libraries.

Android.mk is still just make. Each `include $(BUILD_*)` gets handled in `build/core` to eventually be rewritten as a normal make rule.